# Android: Count strings and drawables

Tags: android, drawable

I'm circulating some drawable images (fx. I have a few images named image_1, image_2 etc.) as header images in a fragment. The images are loaded randomly as I hardcode the number of images available for me, and generate a random index from 0 to this number.

`mHeaderBackgroundImagesCount` is a final:

```
private int getHeaderBackground() {
    // Random index between 0 and mHeaderBackgroundImagesCount
    Random rand = new Random();
    int index = rand.nextInt(mHeaderBackgroundImagesCount) + 1;

    return getResources()
            .getIdentifier("image_" + index, "drawable", getPackageName());
}
```

As hard coding anything isn't normally the way to go in correct programming, I therefore like to dynamically find out how many 'image_X' drawables I have and set it to `mHeaderBackgroundImagesCount`.

I would like to do the same with strings from the `strings.xml` resource file as I'm also circulating some strings on every page load.

**Solution Update**

This update is inspired by *Lalit Poptani's* suggestion below. It includes syntax corrections and optimizations and have been tested to work.

```
private int countResources(String prefix, String type) {
    long id = -1;
    int count = -1;
    while (id != 0) {
        count++;
        id = getResources().getIdentifier(prefix + (count + 1),
                type, getPackageName());
    }

    return count;
}

System.out.println("Drawables counted: " + countResources("image_", "drawable"));
System.out.println("Strings counted: " + countResources("strTitle_", "string"));
```

Note: This method assumes that the resources counted start with index 1 and have no index holes like `image_1` `image_2` `<hole>` `image_4` etc. because it will terminate on first occasion of id=0 thus resulting a faulty count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that your list of drawables will be in a sequence of image_1, image_2,... and so on then you can apply below logic,

```
        int count = 0;
        int RANDOM_COUNT = 10; //which is more than your drawable count 
        for (int i = 1; i < RANDOM_COUNT; i++){
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier("ic_launcher_"+i, 
                                                    "drawable", getPackageName());
            if(id != 0){
                count = + count;
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "This is your final count of drawable with image_x - "+ count);
```

You use this logic because of there will be no drawable with any name as image_x then id will be 0 and you can break the loop

Comment: I've posted a revised procedure in my original post above, which obviate the need for RANDOM_COUNT.

Comment: @Ambran sounds good, so finally which approach you opted to use finally in your code?

Comment: I've used the revised version which I posted above because using a `while` loop eliminates the need for declaring a certain ceiling (RANDOM_COUNT) index like one would need for a `for` loop. The idea is the same, so thanks for that.

Comment: If you have used revised version of while loop as your final conclusion, then you have accepted the wrong answer :)

Comment: I can see your point that your suggestion can be used both for strings and for drawables. I've revised my solution update.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it's possible to dynamically get the number of resources or drawables.

A way to circumvent this issue is to use string arrays as resources in `strings.xml`.

e.g.

```
<resources>
<string-array name="foo_array"> 
    <item>abc1</item> 
    <item>abc2</item> 
    <item>abc3</item> 
</string-array> 

int count = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.foo_array).length;
```

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.